# Lambda or LINQ for Complex Filter?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, collections, lambda

I have a need to filter a large collection of objects (in memory) to select only those which meet ALL of the selected categories.

This is essentially the SQL query I'm looking to replicate, but I've been unable to come up with a good C# alternative:

```
select distinct o.ObjectId
from Object o
join ObjectCategories oc on oc.ObjectId = o.ObjectId
where oc.CategoryId in (1)
and oc.CategoryId in (2)
and oc.CategoryId in (3)
... and so on...
```

...where 1, 2, and 3 represent the values in an indeterminate number of user-selected categories.

Answer (score 0):

Have your user selected category ID's in a List and then you can use Contains.

```
select distinct o.ObjectId
from Object o
join ObjectCategories oc on oc.ObjectId = o.ObjectId
where yourCategoryList.Contains(oc=>oc.categoryID);
```

Comment: The Contains() method will return true if any are present.  I need ALL to be present.

Answer (score 0):

```
var results = ObjectCategories.Where(t2 => ObjectList.Any(t1 => t2.Contains(t1)) == true)
```

you can count the number of matches and if it is equal to the list you are checking against, then you have all the matches.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using Dynamic LINQ. It allows you to use string expressions instead of lambda expressions.  You should be able to do what you want using something similar to:

```
var qry = ObjectCategories.Where( 
    "ObjectList.CategoryId.Contains(1) AND ObjectList.CategoryId.Contains(2) ..."
);
```

There is a pretty solid implemention of Dynamic LINQ here: https://github.com/NArnott/System.Linq.Dynamic